# VS2010 debugger: object inspection & immediate window issues

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty sure I've just accidently turned something on / off... but *what*, I don't know!  **Can anyone tell me why when I'm stepping through my code and I go to inspect one of my objects they all look like this:**

[image: object when in debug mode]

I'm only getting this behaviour on 2 solutions, any new solutions that I create are fine.  Nobody else on my team is having issues like this so I'm guessing it's a setting that's only been applied locally to me.  I also can't use the immediate window properly; for example, if I have an object Foo that's in scope and it has a property Bar; I type Foo.Bar into the immediate window and I'm told Bar doesn't exist, even though it does (see next image):

[image: immediate window for same object]

I've been through the motions of deleting my workspace and getting the latest of everything from TFS, installing all updates and patches to Visual Studio, resetting all Visual Studio user settings, turning off all (only have resharper) addons etc.

Does anyone know what I've done?

Comment: Check whether `Debug -> Option -> general -> Show raw structure of objects in variables windows` is disabled

Comment: Does AgencyName declared in BookingInfo class or in base class?

Comment: @sll Show raw structure... is disabled as usual and I've completely deleted my workspace and then pulled all fresh files down from TFS (and reset all settings on VS) which I think would rule out the .suo possibility?

Comment: @sll AgencyName is in BookingInfo -> I can confirm that last week had I stepped into the same code and checked the AgencyName property of BookingInfo in the immediate window it would have worked.

Comment: Also what is strange is error message you've got. When I requested non existing property name I got an other error message `'className' does not contain a definition for 'TestPropertyName' and no extension method 'TestPropertyName' accepting a first argument of type...`

Comment: Did you turn on native debugging perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so if anyone ever comes across this and has a similar issue I had to do a reinstall of VS.  I probably didn't need to but I couldn't find any answers anywhere else and didn't have the time for an MS support call.